# How to remove the separator \" inside response of my Beautiful Soup

Tags: html

I am trying to use

```
soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'rDivDatosAseg'})
```

But I have a problem, since my html code that I have in the soup is with a type of separators (\")
Therefore it is impossible for me, below I show how the div I want to access looks like:

```
<div class='\"rDivDatosAseg' col-3\"="">
```

I also show a bit the structure that I have:

```
<div><br/><div class='\"rDivDatosAseg' col-3\"=""><span class='\"rSpnTitulo\"'>File number</span><span cetxt\"="" class='\"rSpnValor' vidc0='\"74922\"'>74922</span></div>
```

I tried using:

```
soup.find_all('div', {'class': '\"rDivDatosAseg'})
```

I tried in various ways, but it brings me absolutely nothing, I would like to know how I could search between classes knowing that there are these separators and as far as possible, if the html can be cleaned so that these annoying separators are not shown and can do my search smoothly.

I share a bit of my code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')

def getValBySpanName(name):
    dataArray = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'rDivDatosAseg'})
    print(dataArray)
```

The print returns me []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape the slash if it's part of the string as well.

`\"rDivDatosAseg` is actually `'\\\"rDivDatosAseg'`

Comment: Thank you very much, that was what I was looking for, it worked for me.